# Dentro de una lista como acceder a uno de sus valores declarado como "Object" en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo lo siguiente declarado:

```
List<Object> misObjetos = new List<Object>();
misObjetos.Add( new { precio = 1500 , nombre = "Ciclomotor" } );
misObjetos.Add( new { precio = 300  , nombre = "Patinete"   } );
```

¿ Como accedo por ejemplo al precio del segundo elemento de la lista ?

He probado con `misObjetos[1].precio` pero no funciona.

Comment: Disculpa queria decir misObjetos[1].precio pero aun asi no funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos alternativas, personalmente me gusta mas usar dynamic, que basicamente le dice al compilador que el tipo de datos de la variable se resuelva en modo de ejecucion

```
    List<dynamic> misObjetos = new List<dynamic>();
    misObjetos.Add(new { precio = 1500, nombre = "Ciclomotor" });
    misObjetos.Add(new { precio = 300, nombre = "Patinete" });

    foreach(var obj in misObjetos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.precio);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    //segunda alternativa usando tipos anonimos
    var nodes = (new[] { new { precio = 1500, nombre = "Ciclomotor" } }).ToList();
    nodes.Add(new { precio = 300, nombre = "Patinete" });

    Console.WriteLine(nodes[0].precio);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

La segunda opcion es crear una nueva lista con el primer registro de modo que el compilador sepa la estructura del tipo anonimo. Basado en la respuesta de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203522/how-to-access-property-of-anonymous-type-in-c que es basicamente el mismo caso

Comment: En el cado de usar 'dynamic' si quiero recorrer cada objeto de la lista con un foreach(dynamic item in misObjetos) { string nombre = item.nombre } entonces falla tirandome una excepcion diciendo que 'object' no contiene ninguna definicion para 'nombre'

Comment: foreach(var obj in misObjetos)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(obj.precio);
                Console.ReadLine();
            } lo hiciste de esta forma?? me funciona bien

Comment: @Popularfan edite la respuesta con un ejemplo con foreach

Comment: es raro pongo var y me sigue tirando la excepcion con el foreach...  Desde el debugger dentro del foreach en la ventana de Inmediato si pongo 'obj' me muesta lo siguiente: { precio = 1500, nombre = "Ciclomotor" } precio =1500 nombre="Ciclomotor". Pero si pongo obj.nombre me tira la excepcion.

Comment: @Popularfan que version de Visual studio estas usando?? usas .net framework o .net core? esta solucion funciona con vs 2019 y .net core

Comment: Estoy usando vs2019 con .net framework

Comment: @Popularfan tambien funciona el codigo de la respuesta en .net framework 4.6.1

Comment: Estoy usando net 4.5

Comment: probado en .net framework 4.5 funciona correctamente, probaste copiar el codigo tal cual y ejecutarlo?? en una app de consola nueva para probar

Comment: volvere a revisarlo a ver si se me escapa algo. Pero es rarisimo porque el debugger en ese punto me muestra las variables bien al poner 'obj' pero luego si dentro del debugger pongo obj.nombre me tira la excepcion

Comment: Lo he solucionado usando reflection tal que asi dentro del foreach: obj.GetType().GetProperties()[1].GetValue(obj) porque obj.nombre me tiraba la excepcion

Answer (score 5):

Simplemente no definas el tipo de la variable porque no lo conoces, utiliza `var` en su lugar y un array que luego si deseas puedes volver a `List<T>` mediante `.ToList()` y además tienes que inicializarlos junto con la declaración de la variable:

```
var misObjetos = new[] {
    new { precio = 1500, nombre = "Ciclomotor" },
    new { precio = 300, nombre = "Patinete" },
}.ToList();
```

Otra opción podría ser usando tuplas:

```
var misObjetos = new List<(int precio, string nombre)>();
misObjetos.Add((precio: 1500, nombre: "Ciclomotor"));
misObjetos.Add((precio: 300, nombre: "Patinete"));
```

De ambas maneras podrás acceder a `misObjetos[1].precio`

Comment: Inicialmente misObjetos debe estar vacio y luego ir añadiendo elementos con un .Add . Inicializar entonces var misObjetos = null; no puedo hacerlo

Comment: Entonces inicilizalo con un objeto anónimo cualquiera e inmediatamente quítalo de la lista. Luego ya añades uno por uno. Otra opción es usar tuplas como te lo mencioné. O de lo contrario porque necesariamente tiene que estar vacío al comienzo. Puedes explicar un poco más y mostrar un poco más de código. Creo que te estas cerrando en una solución subóptima.

Comment: Según lo que leo en otros comentarios no necesitas esta lista, si quieres pasar parámetros a un método, simplemente crea una clase con las propiedades deseadas. No luches contra el sistema de tipos. Existe justamente para asegurar que las propiedades existen en tiempo de compilación y no esperar que ocurran errores en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: No me parece buena solucion lo de crear una clase con las propiedades. Prefiero pasar una lista de objetos. Gracias por tus aportes.

Comment: La opción de tuplas la descarto porque me pide actualizar todos los  proyectos a la version C# 7

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a manejar los objetos con la misma estructura siempre puedes declarar una clase con anterioridad:

```
class MiObjeto
{
public int precio { get; set; }

public string nombre { get; set; }
}
```

E indicas que la lista que usaras contiene ese tipo de objeto:

```
    List<MiObjeto> misObjetos = new List<MiObjeto>()
    {
    new MiObjeto() { precio = 1500, nombre = "Ciclomotor" },
    new MiObjeto() { precio = 300, nombre  = "Patinete" }
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < misObjetos.Count; i++)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(misObjetos[i].nombre + " - " + misObjetos[i].precio);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: La solución de la clase no me sirve para lo que estoy haciendo.

Comment: Tal vez si explicas que estas haciendo se te pueda dar una solucion mejor @Popularfan

Comment: Siplemente es pasar parametros a una funcion por medio de una lista por ejemplo, o por medio de un diccionario. Y esos parametros cada uno tiene diferente tipo. Luego recuperarlos segun la key.

Comment: Si sabes exactamente cuáles son esos parámetros, olvidate de la lista y pasalos directamente, de lo contrario tu mismo te has dado la respuesta, es un Dictionary. Tu pregunta parece no tener relación con el código que has puesto.

Comment: No se si el Dicionario es la manera mas optima, y  la Lista no me deberia dar problemas.

Comment: Con todo respeto tu pregunta no esta clara. Caes en el clásica situación de tener el problema _X_ pero preguntar como se hace _Y_, en lugar de preguntar por _X_. Cuando la gente te responde por _Y_ mencionas que no aplica la solución por motivos que no habías explicado anteriormente. Entiende que _Y_ es solo un medio (y además el incorrecto) para solucionar _X_ que es el fin. En lugar acepta la solución _Z_ que te estamos planteando

Comment: Gracias por tu opinión... al final me funciono List<Object> pero accediendo con Reflection